# I don't want to create another db table to filter who is team and who is friend, please help me

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I don't want to creater another table called friends at strapi and link it again to visual studio code, so I have a Characters table for all team and friends. So I want to input only new data at Characters , but filter it to know which one is friend or team. So I've tried  to make a function for it to know's which is a friend, that I've determined with if you have only  start date your a team if you have both start and end date you are friend. The source code at the file is this:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css'
import fetchFromCMS from '../../lib/service';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"; // requires a loader
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const characters = await fetchFromCMS('characters');
    return {
      props: { characters},
      revalidate: 1,
    };
  }

function sortByDate(a , b){
  return new Date(a.StartDate) - new Date(b.StartDate);
}
function isFirend(a ){ 
  var bool = true;
  new Date(a.EndDate) !=  null? bool = true : bool= false;
 
  return  bool  ;
}

const charactersItem = ({ characters }) => {

        return (
      
          <Layout>
          <div className={styles.container}>
            <Head>
              <title>Characters</title>
            </Head>
      
            <main className={styles.main}  id="page-top">
                         {/*///Team*/ } 
          <section className="bg-light page-section">            
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 className="section-heading text-uppercase">Our Amazing Team</h2>
                <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted">Check out our fantastic team.</h3>
              </div>
            </div>  
            <div className="row">          
            {characters.sort().map((character) => (
                <div className="col-sm-4">
                  <a href={`/Team/${character.Slug}`}>
                  <div className="team-member">        
                    <img className="mx-auto rounded-circle" src={character.Image.url} alt=""></img> 
                    <h4 className="text-muted">{character.PaineapleName}</h4>         
                </div>
                </a>  
              </div> 
            
              )) 
            }  
             </div>            
            
          </div>
          </section> 
                            {/*//friends*/} 
                           { <section className="bg-light page-section">            
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 className="section-heading text-uppercase">Our Amazing Friends</h2>
                <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted">Check out our fantastic team.</h3>
              </div>
            </div>  
            <div className="row">          
            {characters.sort(character.EndDate).map((character) => (
                <div className="col-sm-4">
                  <a href={`/Team/${character.Slug}`}>
                  <div className="team-member">        
                    <img className="mx-auto rounded-circle" src={character.Image.url} alt=""></img> 
                    <h4 className="text-muted">{character.PaineapleName}</h4>         
                </div>
                </a>  
              </div> 
            
              )) 
            }
             </div>            
            
          </div>
          </section> }
          </main>
           
          </div>
          </Layout>
        )   
};

export default charactersItem;
```

The results aren't what I've expected because and the error it shows is this one: [image]

I try other solutions and the only way I did something nearby the objective it duplicated, I mean with this, it duplicated the info instead of filter which one is friend.

Answer (score 0):

character.endDate is not a compare function. It's possible Characters is the issue but you should isolate each issue one by one to troubleshoot.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: when I go to console it says undefined and I'm not gething the value for it, that's other problem I'm having with this solution.

Comment: So it's not finding the array i pretend